# Terminal - Search entire directory for keyword

Tags: command-line, directory, search, find

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project so I have to manage multiple files. I think I made a syntax mistake somewhere but I'm not sure well. It would be awesome if I could search for a keyword through the entire project directory.

I'm sure there's some command on Terminal, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: did you want to find the files which contain a specific keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the recursive mode of grep:

```
grep -R pattern directory
```

`ack` (`ack-grep` on Ubuntu) and [`ag`](http://geoff.greer.fm/2011/12/27/the-silver-searcher-better-than-ack/) are also good for this.

Comment: +1 but `ack`? You mean `ack-grep`? And what is `ag`? Did you mean `agrep`?

Comment: I think it should be option `-r` (`--recursive`) instead of `-R` (`--dereference-recursive`), as `-R` would follow symlinks out of the project directory.

Answer (score 5):

```
cd ~/path/to/your/directory
grep -rwI KeywordCaseSensitive *
```

Explanateion:

`-r` search recursively
`w` search for a word only (i.e. surrounded by white space and/or punctuation)
`I` ignore binary files

You may consider option `-i` (ignore case).